# Is there anyway to rewrite this function with async in the first function. Instead of a "new Promise"?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

This is the function that is working.

```js
const delayedColorChange = (color, delay) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
      resolve();
    }, delay);
  });
};

const rainbow = async() => {
  await delayedColorChange('red', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('orange', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('yellow', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('green', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('blue', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('indigo', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('violet', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('pink', 1000);
  return 'ALL DONE';
};

rainbow().then(console.log);
```

Trying to make delayedColorChange into an async function.

```
const delayedColorChange = async (color, delay) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }, delay);
};
```

In this code the backgrounColor on the website is going straight to pink.
why is that?

Basically, is there any way to make delayedColorChange into an async function?
To my understanding, async functions returns a promise, so, why not just use an async function, instead of having to create a "new Promise" in a regular function?.

Is this even possible?

Sorry for the loaded post.

Comment: No - but why do you want/think you need to? And to be complete (avoid criticism), you should add `.then(console.log)` on the call to `rainbow()`

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to rewrite this function with async in the first function. Instead of a “new Promise”?

No, there is not.  Not if you want the function to return a promise that is tied to when the timer fires.

`async` functions are very useful when you are calling functions that already return promises and you want to use `await` to help with the control flow on those existing promise-returning functions.

But, when you have a function like `setTimeout()` that does not use a promise at all and you want to "promisify" it so you can use promise-based control flow, you will have to use some means of making a new promise and wrapping the existing callback in that new promise.  For `setTimeout()`, the code you show is the standard way to do that.

It is a bit more common and generically useful to promisify just the timer because then you can use this lots of places and it is generally recommended when promisifying things to promisify at the lowest level (because it's more extensible and you build all your logic on top of promise-based control flow):

```
// promise-based timer
function delay(t, v) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, t, v);
    });
}

const delayedColorChange = (color, t) => {
    return delay(t).then(() => {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
    });
};
```

> In this code the backgroundColor on the website is going straight to pink. why is that?

Your snippet in your question does not go straight to pink (if you just hit "run code snippet" right in your question) so if your real web page is going straight to pink, then something must be different in that implementation from this one.

Comment: You could do `await sleep(delay); document.body.style.backgroundColor = color` but then again, that just moves the promise to another place.

Comment: @VLAZ - Yeah, I extended my answer to something like that since it's more extensible to promisify just the timer and then build on top of that.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a promise-based generic `sleep` function -

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

async delayedColorChange (color, delay)
{ await sleep(delay)
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Here's how I might write `rainbow` -

```js
const sleep = ms =>
  new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))

const setBackgroundColor = (e, color) =>
 e.style.backgroundColor = color

async function rainbow (e, colors, i = 0)
{ while (true)
  { setBackgroundColor(e, colors[i])
    i = (i + 1) % colors.length
    await sleep(600)
  }
}

const colors =
  ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"]
  
rainbow(document.body, colors)
```

```css
body {
  transition: background-color .6s;
}
```

Comment: @VLAZ, thanks I added CSS transition to make it less seizure-inducing ^^

Answer (score 0):

First, it's worth noting that `setTimeout` does not guarantee that your callback will be executed in exactly `delay` milliseconds; it adds your callback function to the [JS event queue](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop) after `delay` milliseconds. If there are long-running functions in line in front of this callback then your callback gets delayed longer. I don't know if that is relevant to what you're doing here, but it's good to keep in mind.

This also explains why your last code snippet goes directly to pink. You are adding a series of functions to the event queue all 1 second from now and they all execute extremely quickly. The last one leaves the background pink, so that's all you're able to observe on the page.

Your first function can be a little more concise, which should help readability in a year when you revisit this, but there isn't a JS function (that I'm aware of) that performs asynchronous sleeping.

```js
const delayedColorChange = async(color, delay) => {
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
};

const rainbow = async() => {
  await delayedColorChange('red', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('orange', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('yellow', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('green', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('blue', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('indigo', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('violet', 1000);
  await delayedColorChange('pink', 1000);
  return 'ALL DONE';
};

rainbow().then(console.log);
```

Adding the `await` to `delayedColorChange` is what introduces the delay in the promise being returned. Without an `await`, your `async` function executes synchronously and returns an already resolved promise.